# Can I Validate x509 ClientCertificate on a WCF web service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate, client-certificates

Do not really know how x509 works.

If I have a Web Service that needs to authenticate and validate the client, and he uses a ClientCertificate, could he send me some information that I could then validate against?

I do not create the Web Site itself so I can't be sure they would do it right. I don't wan't to allow someone to say to the Web Service "It's okay, I ClientCertificated him and he's good".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [custom client certificate validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx) but its usage will be different based on the way how do you use the client certificate. If you use pure message security your validator will be the only component used to validate the certificate. If you use HTTPS with client certificate (transport security) the certificate will be first validated by Windows (= your service hosting server must trust the certificate) and after that it will be passed to WCF and validated by your validator.

Comment: So I can forward the certificate to WCF to validate it there. Sounds like what I was looking for.

Comment: It depends what you mean by forward. This certificate validation works when client calls the service. If you want anything else like using WCF to validate certificates passed to other destination it will be completely custom solution - and in such case you should really study how certificates works otherwise your solution would be insecure.

Comment: Well I'm totally lost on these Client Certs and how things like Web Sites and Web Services handles them. Everywhere I read about them they use terms like you should already know the basics. Is there a basic tutorial? There is a website somewhere out there using a WCF service I create. They validate someone using a ClientCertificate, but that isn't enough for my WCF service, I want to validate the Certificate as well to ensure that I'm not being cheated.